# object Def is not a member of package sbt

Tags: sbt, fedora, playframework-2.1

> sbt.version=0.12.4 (I use play 2.1.3)

I have an error when use sbt:

```
> sbt
<expected-type>:1: error: object Def is not a member of package sbt
sbt.Def.SettingsDefinition
    ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

It's on Fedora 22 x86_64. This project built perfectly on ubuntu.

I cannot update the version of sbt.

Any ideas?

Comment: also asked at https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2220

Comment: What does the launch script you're using look like? I'm only guessing, but maybe you're using an old launch script that tries to download some JAR from a no-longer valid location (and perhaps uses `curl` but doesn't use the flag that asks `curl` to follow redirects).

Comment: I've found. That it doesn't work with *plugins.sbt*. Look at the comment with  script https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2220#issuecomment-143026008

Comment: Consider using a different launch script, if the one Fedora supplied you with doesn't work. (There is nothing sacrosanct about that particular launch script.) For example, lots of people use https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras. As I showed in my comments on the GitHub issue, the minimum needed is to grab a launch jar and then run `java` on it.

Comment: Different launch script helped, thanks